# Clearing drupal's cache causes an error 403 in some pages of my site

Tags: views, caching

When I empty all drupal's caches in my website,  I get a 403 error in some pages of my site, I solved this problem by enabling or disabling the views UI Module, but it gets very annoying to do this manipulation every time the cache is flushed.

Someone has an explanation for this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: When you disable/enable caches are also cleared. Have you tried disabling/enabling other modules or doest it only work with views module? Maybe you have a mysql problem and caches are not cleared successfully. Have you tried to flush twice? Are you clearing it by drush or by UI?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.
I tried to clear the cache twice, but that does not solve the problem, it works with other modules also, i must enable or disable any module to solve the issue.
 I'm clearing it by the UI, clearing it by drush (drush cc all) does not cause the problem.

Comment: Edit : It only works with views UI module.

Comment: Are the 403 pages views pages? How much time does your clear cache take? Maybe you have a problem with your max_execution_time, Have you tried to increase it?

Comment: The 403 pages are taxonomy and generic content pages.
I tried to increase it, I don't think it's due to this.